# Remove icon from jfilechoser

Tags: java, swing, icons, jfilechooser

I want to remove the icon from a jfilechoser named "choser". I am using this but nothing changes:

```
    Frame window=new Frame();
    window.setIconImage(null);
    int result=choser.showSaveDialog(window);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which icon ? do you mean java icon in the header ?

Comment: yes. I want to have no icon at all

Comment: Create an instance of JFielChooser, create a JDialog, add the chooser to the dialog...